# Different Colour for @Mentions

Tags: feature-request, design

When a comments section gets long, the @mentions can become a bit distracting. Would they be better off in a dark grey sort of colour?

Here is a screenshot of a comment I coded to help explain:

[image: Grey @Mention]

The @User blends nicely with the timestamp.

Comment: There's not much we child metas can do about design elements - better to ask on [Meta.se]. Of course, the specific color of the @ mention might have to vary with the specific site's design. Maybe the primary suggestion would be to always use the same color as the time stamp,

Comment: I quite like the idea in principle, but as @Dan Bron says, it's probably an SE Meta issue. And I can see problems for the techies deciding *how much text to highlight*. They can't just stop at the first space, and I don't think they're going to prevent us from citing a username that maybe doesn't even appear on the same page (or even *exist!* :) But perhaps they were anticipating this very feature a while ago when they started restricting multiple occurrences of @ + text in a comment (to stop us using it as a general-purpose "formatting" tool).

Comment: This would definitely be a network-wide consideration, so you'd want to post this on [meta.se]. When / if you do that, **make sure you clearly post 2 screenshots: the existing behavior vs. the proposed behavior** (it took me a little while to figure out exactly what you were asking for). *Personally (just speaking for myself, not the company)*, I feel this change could make the "1 mention maximum" behavior easier to discover / visualize. On the other hand, it *might* be quite difficult to implement.

Comment: Is there an easy way to migrate this question, or do I need superuser privileges?

Comment: Moderators can migrate this. But please follow @Thomas' suggestion of adding another screenshot, and possibly include a freehand red outline highlighting the difference between them, because freehand circles always go down well. However, you may want to think about what happens in this comment: the OP gets a ping because it's a comment on the question, and Thomas does too. But the "highlight" would be in the middle of a sentence. Or would such mentions in the middle of text not be differentiated?

Comment: @AndrewLeach +1 for '...freehand circles always go down well.' And no, only the initial (at)mention would be greyed; any in-body ones after the start of the comment would be normal colour. e.g. In the comment *(at)User1 (at)User2 Lorem ipsum (at)User3 Lorum ipsum*, only (at)User1 and (at)User2 would be in grey.

Comment: OK. Certainly the iPad app won't actually allow more than one @ mention per comment; not sure about the web interface. But I'm just pointing out that the question needs to be as complete as possible before it's migrated. (Comments like this can be deleted prior to migration as no longer relevant to what is then an MSE question.)

Comment: The problem is that mentions can come anywhere in a comment... they don't *have* to be at the beginning... so it would certainly be more odd to see an oddly-colored @ mention in the middle of a post, much as how @AndrewLeach did in his earlier post and I just did here.